# VSCode: How do I disable vscode from scrolling to where I click?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't find out how to disable this feature. VSCode will scroll to wherever I click in the text editor. It ends up scrolling the text as I press down to click and text gets highlighted until I release the click. This is very annoying. I have to click very very lightly in order to prevent this from happening. How do I disable this scroll-to-click feature.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue. More information please. Can you include a screen gif of what's actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the feature that allows the behavior to happen. It is called "Cursor Surrounding Lines".

> Editor: Cursor Surrounding Lines
> Controls the minimal number of visible leading and trailing lines surrounding the cursor. Known as 'scrollOff' or 'scrollOffset' in some other editors.

The value was set to 200, so I just set it to 0. Fixed the issue.